# how to cache user details in a partial in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In the header of every page I am showing Username and User points. This is being pulled in from a partial (which gets the points from the database).

How can I cache this partial so that across each page I avoid having to check the database for the users points, and after 24hrs it can look again (cache expires). Also if the user logs off and someone else logs in it will show the new username and points (not the previously cached one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is user specific so I would store it in a persistent cookie. So when a user authenticates you could query the database to fetch the required information and issue a persistent cookie which will expire in 24h. Then in the partial you would check whether the cookie exists and fetch the necessary data from this cookie and if the cookie doesn't exist query the database and reemit the cookie. When the user logs out you could remove the cookie although that's not strictly necessary because when he logs back in (with the same or other username) you would query the database once again and reemit the cookie.

And because we live in 2011 and HTML5 is knocking on our doors instead of cookies I would probably use the [HTML5 Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) and if the browser doesn't support it fallback to cookies.

Answer (score 1):

As Darin mentioned, local storage may be an option but cookies are more widely supported and the fallback mechanism would certainly work.

However, depending on what you need to store, you probably don't want to be storing any sensitive information in a cookie or any sort of complex data, so data in the cookie would not scale if you begin adding additional pieces of data you need to track. I generally only use cookies for keying off something I need to query for from the db or a server-side cache.

If you using an ORM, such as NHibernate, explicit caching within the application is probably not something you would need to greatly concern yourself with as the data would be cached by the ORM's caching provider (local or distributed options available).

Since this is user-specific, another option is to store this information in the session state server-side when the user authenticates (which can optionally use a cookie).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean: 'I don't want to write the same code in each action to load my user data and pass it to the view, which would render partial view instead'?

If yes, than change your **RenderPartial** to **RenderAction** and put your logic for getting user stats from db there.

But this code will execute each time the user requests the page.

You might want to consider putting the values in HttpCache (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx) so you don't have to go to db for every request.

Comment: This is one way to do it. For the action give it an `OutputCache` attribute that expires every 24 hours and you should be set.